How to distinguish files with the same path in a container using perf buildid-list
I run perf record -a -- sleep 3 on the host machine for sampling. There may be binaries with the same path but different buildids in different containers. For example, container A has /tmp/a.out, and container B also has /tmp/a.out. The final sampled perf.data can only output one of the buildids through perf buildid-list.
Note: The actual situation is that I can only run perf once on the host machine to sample processes in all containers, and cannot run perf in each container in turn.
